# Pandas get mean value per (row,col) across list of dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dictionary of dataframes:

```
{1 : df1, 2 : df2 .. }
```

All dataframe are with the same shapes. (but different number of rows).
I want to create the dataframe where every column is the mean of this column for this row.
So if:

```
df1 : A  B  C
      2  4  6
      1  3  5
df2 : A  B  C
      0  2  8
      7  9  5
```

I will get:

```
new_df:  A  B  C 
         1  3  7
         4  6  5
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `concat()` and `mean()`:

```
out=pd.concat(d.values()).mean(level=0)
```

OR

```
out=pd.concat(d).mean(level=1)
```

**Note:** here `d` is your dictionary of dataframes

output of `out`:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   3   7
1   4   6   5
```